# test on a value and not (test on a value) are false

Tags: sql, oracle

```
WITH a as 
     (  select       1  b,   null     c from dual)  
select       *  from     a
```

As expected: one line is returned

```
WITH a as 
     (  select       1  b,   null     c from dual)  
select       *  from     a
where c=1
```

As expected: no line is returned. c is null. therefore it can't be 1

```
WITH a as 
     (  select       1  b,   null     c from dual)  
select       *  from     a
where not(c=1 )
```

I didn't expected that. No lines are returned. c=1 is false. Therefore not (c=1) should be true

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=2ad94bfd758434e874f327970ad46880)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NULL is the unknown value. You cannot compare it.

- NULL = 1 results in "unknown"
- NULL <> 1 results in "unknown"
- NOT (NULL = 1) results in "unknown"

In a `WHERE` clause the condition must be true for the row to be returned, though.

One way to go about this is to explicitely consider nulls:

```
WHERE (c <> 1 OR c IS NULL)
```

Or (for the lack of standard SQL's `IS DISTINCT FROM`) with Oracle's `DECODE`:

```
WHERE DECODE(c, 1, 'same', 'different') = 'different'
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second query:

```sql
WITH a AS (
    SELECT 1 b, NULL c
    FROM dual
)

SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE NOT (c = 1);
```

The expression `c = 1`, when the value of `c` be null, is *unknown*.  This means that it cannot be said for certainty whether `c` does, or does not, equal 1.  As a result, the single record which your CTE defines is not returned for this query.

Comment: CTE: what is that?

Comment: CTE = common table expression.  You used a CTE when you defined your SQL using `WITH`.